# Multiple condition in single XSLT when statement

Tags: xslt

When I was checking the code, I got to see multiple conditions in single test statement. It didn't give me correct result.

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(ws:Additional_Information/ws:Company/@ws:PriorValue = 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E')and ws:Eligibility='false'">
<xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:Additional_Information/ws:Employee_Status"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But when I started using like the below, I got the correct answer.

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(ws:Additional_Information/ws:Company/@ws:PriorValue = 'A' or ws:Additional_Information/ws:Company/@ws:PriorValue ='B' or ws:Additional_Information/ws:Company/@ws:PriorValue ='C' or ws:Additional_Information/ws:Company/@ws:PriorValue ='D' or ws:Additional_Information/ws:Company/@ws:PriorValue ='E')and ws:Eligibility='false'">
<xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="ws:Additional_Information/ws:Employee_Status"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Why the first one is not correct?

Answer (score 2):

To simplify things, your first "test" expression is of the following form

```
@attr = 'A' or 'B'
```

In some languages, such a syntax would not even be allowed. It is effectively the same as doing this:

```
(@attr = 'A') or ('B')
```

You are asking "*Is the expression `attr = 'A'` true OR is the expression `'B'` true*?". In XSLT, asking "*is the expression `'B'` true?*" would actually return true because the string 'B' is non-empty. Thus the whole expression will always be true regardless of the attribute value.

So, you have to write `@attr = 'A' or @attr = 'B'` here.

If you are looking for some shorter syntax, if you can use XSLT 2.0, you can write this:

```
@attr = ('a', 'b')
```

Which is like saying "*Is the @attr equal to any value in the sequence?*"

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first expression is that [`or` operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans) is a logical operator, not a sequence concatenator. So this expression `@ws:PriorValue = 'A' or 'B'` makes no sense.

In XPath 1.0, one idiom for simplify multiple comparison over the same nodeset is to use the dot `.` expression like this:

```
ws:Additional_Information
   /ws:Company
      /@ws:PriorValue[.='A' or .='B' or .='C' or .='D' or .='E']
and ws:Eligibility='false'
```

Another one is to use [`contains` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) like this:

```
ws:Additional_Information
   /ws:Company
      /@ws:PriorValue[
         contains(' A B C D E ', concat(' ',.,' '))
      ]
and ws:Eligibility='false'
```